# Cargar datos de 2 tablas distintas en ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Tengo el siguiente método en el cual cargo mis datos de acuerdo al id de mi tabla paciente para visualizar en un pequeño formulario de informacion como se ve a continuación en el código, la pregunta es puedo añadir mediante un query que en base al código del odontólogo me visualice el nombre del doctor de mi tabla odontólogo en el cual llamo mediante `MODELO_ODONTOLOGO`

```
 public List<MODELO_PACIENTE> get_Pacientes_Async(String valor, int id)
        {
            List<MODELO_PACIENTE> ListaTPacientes;
            List<MODELO_ODONTOLOGO> ListaTOdon;
            var PacienteLista = new List<MODELO_PACIENTE>();
            if (valor == null && id.Equals(0))
            {
                ListaTPacientes = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.ToList();
                ListaTOdon = _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                if (id.Equals(0))
                {
                    ListaTPacientes = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.Where(u => u.PAC_CODIGO.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_NOMBRE.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_APELLIDO.StartsWith(valor)).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    ListaTPacientes = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.Where(u => u.PAC_ID.Equals(id)).ToList();
                }
            }
            if (!ListaTPacientes.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                foreach (var item in ListaTPacientes)
                {
                    PacienteLista.Add(new MODELO_PACIENTE
                    {
                        PAC_ID = item.PAC_ID,
                        PAC_RUT = item.PAC_RUT,
                        PAC_CODIGO = item.PAC_CODIGO,
                        PAC_COD_ODONT = item.PAC_COD_ODONT + AÑADIR UN QUERY EN BASE AL CODIGO DEL DOCTOR PODER CARGAR EL NOMBRE Y VISUALIZAR EN EL DETALLE
                        PAC_FECHA_NAC = item.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                        PAC_FEC_ACT = item.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                        PAC_FEC_REG = item.PAC_FEC_REG,
                        PAC_NOMBRE = item.PAC_NOMBRE,
                        PAC_APELLIDO = item.PAC_APELLIDO,
                        PAC_CORREO = item.PAC_CORREO,
                        PAC_TELEFONO = item.PAC_TELEFONO,
                        PAC_COMUNA = item.PAC_COMUNA,
                        PAC_DIRECCION = item.PAC_DIRECCION,
                        PAC_CONVENIO = item.PAC_CONVENIO,
                        PAC_OBSERVACIONES = item.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                        PAC_EDAD = item.PAC_EDAD,
                        PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS = item.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                        PAC_PREVISIONES = item.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                        PAC_REPRESENTANTE = item.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                        PAC_SEXO = item.PAC_SEXO,
                        PAC_IMAGEN = item.PAC_IMAGEN,
                    });
                }
            }
            return PacienteLista;
        }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Lo que requieres es un ViewModel que tenga las propiedades que necesitas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para no dejar la pregunta sin respuesta.

```
var ListaTPaciente = (from p in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                  join o in _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO on p.PAC_COD_ODONT equals o.ODONT_CODIGO
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      p.PAC_ID,
                                      p.PAC_CODIGO,
                                      p.PAC_NOMBRE,
                                      p.PAC_APELLIDO,
                                      p.PAC_SEXO,
                                      p.PAC_RUT,
                                      p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                      p.PAC_EDAD,
                                      p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                                      p.PAC_DIRECCION,
                                      p.PAC_COMUNA,
                                      p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                      p.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                      p.PAC_CORREO,
                                      p.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                      p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                      p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                      p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                                      p.PAC_IMAGEN,
                                      p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                                      p.PAC_FEC_REG,
                                      o.ODONT_CODIGO,
                                      o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                                      o.ODONT_NOMBRE
                                  }).OrderBy(u => u.PAC_ID).ToList();
            if (valor == null && id.Equals(0))
            {
                ListaTPaciente = (from p in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                  join o in _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO on p.PAC_COD_ODONT equals o.ODONT_CODIGO
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      p.PAC_ID,
                                      p.PAC_CODIGO,
                                      p.PAC_NOMBRE,
                                      p.PAC_APELLIDO,
                                      p.PAC_SEXO,
                                      p.PAC_RUT,
                                      p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                      p.PAC_EDAD,
                                      p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                                      p.PAC_DIRECCION,
                                      p.PAC_COMUNA,
                                      p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                      p.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                      p.PAC_CORREO,
                                      p.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                      p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                      p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                      p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                                      p.PAC_IMAGEN,
                                      p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                                      p.PAC_FEC_REG,
                                      o.ODONT_CODIGO,
                                      o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                                      o.ODONT_NOMBRE
                                  }).OrderBy(u => u.PAC_ID).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                if (id.Equals(0))
                {
                    //   var query = String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor) ? ListaTPaciente
                    //: id.Equals(0) ? ListaTPaciente.Where(u => u.PAC_CODIGO.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_NOMBRE.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_APELLIDO.StartsWith(valor)).ToList() : ListaTPaciente.Where(u => u.PAC_ID.Equals(id)).ToList();
                    ListaTPaciente = (from p in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                      join o in _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO on p.PAC_COD_ODONT equals o.ODONT_CODIGO
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          p.PAC_ID,
                                          p.PAC_CODIGO,
                                          p.PAC_NOMBRE,
                                          p.PAC_APELLIDO,
                                          p.PAC_SEXO,
                                          p.PAC_RUT,
                                          p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                          p.PAC_EDAD,
                                          p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                                          p.PAC_DIRECCION,
                                          p.PAC_COMUNA,
                                          p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                          p.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                          p.PAC_CORREO,
                                          p.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                          p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                          p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                          p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                                          p.PAC_IMAGEN,
                                          p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                                          p.PAC_FEC_REG,
                                          o.ODONT_CODIGO,
                                          o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                                          o.ODONT_NOMBRE
                                      }).Where(u => u.PAC_CODIGO.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_NOMBRE.StartsWith(valor) || u.PAC_APELLIDO.StartsWith(valor)).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    ListaTPaciente = (from p in _context.TBL_PACIENTE
                                      join o in _context.TBL_ODONTOLOGO on p.PAC_COD_ODONT equals o.ODONT_CODIGO
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          p.PAC_ID,
                                          p.PAC_CODIGO,
                                          p.PAC_NOMBRE,
                                          p.PAC_APELLIDO,
                                          p.PAC_SEXO,
                                          p.PAC_RUT,
                                          p.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                                          p.PAC_EDAD,
                                          p.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                                          p.PAC_DIRECCION,
                                          p.PAC_COMUNA,
                                          p.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                                          p.PAC_TELEFONO,
                                          p.PAC_CORREO,
                                          p.PAC_CONVENIO,
                                          p.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                                          p.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                                          p.PAC_COD_ODONT,
                                          p.PAC_IMAGEN,
                                          p.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                                          p.PAC_FEC_REG,
                                          o.ODONT_CODIGO,
                                          o.ODONT_APELLIDO,
                                          o.ODONT_NOMBRE
                                      }).Where(u => u.PAC_ID.Equals(id)).ToList();
                }
            }

            if (!ListaTPaciente.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                foreach (var item in ListaTPaciente)
                {
                    PacienteLista.Add(new MODELO_PACIENTE
                    {
                        PAC_ID = item.PAC_ID,
                        PAC_RUT = item.PAC_RUT,
                        PAC_CODIGO = item.PAC_CODIGO,
                        PAC_COD_ODONT = item.PAC_COD_ODONT + '-' + item.ODONT_APELLIDO + ' ' + item.ODONT_NOMBRE,
                        PAC_FECHA_NAC = item.PAC_FECHA_NAC,
                        PAC_FEC_ACT = item.PAC_FEC_ACT,
                        PAC_FEC_REG = item.PAC_FEC_REG,
                        PAC_NOMBRE = item.PAC_NOMBRE,
                        PAC_APELLIDO = item.PAC_APELLIDO,
                        PAC_CORREO = item.PAC_CORREO,
                        PAC_TELEFONO = item.PAC_TELEFONO,
                        PAC_COMUNA = item.PAC_COMUNA,
                        PAC_DIRECCION = item.PAC_DIRECCION,
                        PAC_CONVENIO = item.PAC_CONVENIO,
                        PAC_OBSERVACIONES = item.PAC_OBSERVACIONES,
                        PAC_EDAD = item.PAC_EDAD,
                        PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS = item.PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS,
                        PAC_PREVISIONES = item.PAC_PREVISIONES,
                        PAC_REPRESENTANTE = item.PAC_REPRESENTANTE,
                        PAC_SEXO = item.PAC_SEXO,
                        PAC_IMAGEN = item.PAC_IMAGEN,
                    });
                }

            }
        
        return PacienteLista;
```